# Generating a pivot table from a sql query

Tags: javascript, php, html, postgresql, pivot-table

I have a project that consist of a function that generate a table based on some filter. Then, I found a problem that when some combination of some filter are return nothing so, when it rendered in browser as a table is less than number of combination.
To achieve it, I want to give "-" mark to the loss record that not saved in the table.

My first approach is check one-by-one the array with the filter and if the condition is match to 'loss rows', it will push array untill all missing record in result is filled with '-'. But, it'll dealing with time because, the last must be sorted again and then to be constructed into the wanted table.

Sample schema of main table "A":

```
 amount_of_product, id_product, id_people, id_place.
```

The primary key columns are:

```
 id_product, id_people, id_place.
```

The content of the main table is:

```
23456, book-a, 1, aa
5678, book-b, 1, cc
2587, book-b, 1, aa
```

The source query will be something like:

```
select * from A
where
    id_product in ('book-a', 'book-b')
    and id_people in ('1') and id_place in ('aa', 'bb', 'cc')
order by id_product, id_place
```

Then, we want to show in a table view (html) all combinations of all selected filters. 6 rows should be rendered, with empty cells shown as `"-"`.

Sample result table:

[image: Sample 1]

Can I do it efficiently or are there any solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show some scnreehots, jsfiddle, code,..

Comment: In Oracle, you would use `pivot` : `select * from A pivot(sum(amount_of_product) for id_place in ('aa','bb','cc'))`. The postgresql [`crosstab`](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/index.php?/archives/14-CrossTab-Queries-in-PostgreSQL-using-tablefunc-contrib.html) function should provide similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for some advice above.
I've try to use crosstab function in postgresql to produce the pivot table but I can't produce for more complex table.

So, I use another approach to retrieve all datas based on combination row-coloumn gradually (example query from id_place 'aa', id_people '1', id-product 'aa' etc) and contruct each table head row and coloumn then contruct the data.

Regard